# Functional analysis. Finite-dimensional and infinite-dimensional linear spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

> Show that $C[a,b]$ is infinite-dimensional. Consider the sequence of functions $1, t, t^2, \ldots , t^n,\ldots$ and show that $1, t, t^2, \ldots, t^n$ are linearly independent for any natural $n$. Show that $C^k[a,b]$ also infinite-dimensional.

Please, help me. I don't now how I can start doing it.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you at least tried small values of $n$?  For instance: can you show that $1,t$ are linearly independent? How did you do so?  What about $1,t,t^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ ,  $a_0,a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb R$ and

$p(t):= a_0+a_1t+...+a_nt^n$.

You have to show: if $p(t)=0$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$, then $a_0=a_1=...=a_n$.

Your turn !

Answer (score 0):

Once you have proven that $\{1,t,...,t^{n}\}$ is linearly-independant, the second step could go like this:

If $C[a,b]$ was finite-dimensional, let $N$ be its dimension.
Then any family of $N$ linearly-independant elements of $C[a,b]$ should be a base of $C[a,b]$. For instance, $\{1,t,...,t^{N-1}\}$.

Can you then find a function in $C[a,b]$ that is not a linear combinaison of $\{1,t,...,t^{N-1}\}$ ? That would provide a contradiction and solve the exercise... Don't look too far nor too complicated...